# Trying to connect to an SSH server on one machine and it works fine. Not on the other

Tags: ssh, osx

```
~$ ssh -v raina@45.79.8.241
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.7
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 25: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 45.79.8.241 [45.79.8.241] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/raina/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/raina/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/raina/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/raina/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/raina/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/raina/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/raina/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/raina/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/raina/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.1p1-hpn14v9
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.1p1-hpn14v9 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 45.79.8.241:22 as 'raina'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:LQ1K6AddhnCMm3KVYX46yS9RZFcM8szWf+tpuCgtb/E
debug1: Host '45.79.8.241' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/raina/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key:
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 45.79.8.241 ([45.79.8.241]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
```

Other machine:

```
$ ssh -v raina@45.79.8.241
OpenSSH_7.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
debug1: Connecting to 45.79.8.241 [45.79.8.241] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Administrator/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Administrator/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Administrator/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Administrator/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Administrator/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Administrator/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.1p1-hpn14v9
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.1p1-hpn14v9 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 45.79.8.241:22 as 'raina'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:LQ1K6AddhnCMm3KVYX46yS9RZFcM8szWf+tpuCgtb/E
debug1: Host '45.79.8.241' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/Administrator/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Administrator/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Administrator/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Administrator/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

What gives? Same id_rsa in both

Comment: What does the `authorized_keys` entry look like on the remote node?

Comment: please help....

Comment: like this http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=eqvieeuG

Comment: What about `ssh-add -l` on the working host?

Comment: what command is that?

Comment: 4096 SHA256:Nub+UPUpo5xrcrO4CcOfesacA8GAqf4Sh+L3PWJvhcY  (RSA) on the mac

Comment: Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Comment: on the other box

Comment: Your MAC used the SSH key in the `ssh-agent` keyring, which was likely not the same as `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. You are using different keys on each system.

Comment: How can I force it to use the one in .ssh

Comment: `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa`, but that's just going to cause it to fail in both places, instead of just the second box. Just add `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` on the second box to the `authorized_keys` file on the remote node.

Comment: No way. There was definitely an easier way to make this work. Your telling me I need to change the authorized_keys file for every single box I want to connect to now? That can't be right.

Comment: I used to be able to just copy the private key to any computer I wanted to use to connect to this box.

Comment: figured it out. just need to add the .id_rsa file to the keyring and then copy-id again. then the private key works from any device.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the issue. OSX was using it's own keychain and not the one in .ssh like a normal BSD or Linux system.

I just needed to add the id_rsa file to the keychain and then recopy.

The private key worked fine after that.

Got the info from here:
http://fplanque.com/dev/mac/secure-ssh-private-keys-on-mac-osx-10-5